# In app Billing - onIabPurchaseFinished never called, but purchase is successful

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I'm having problems with the Google App Billing service. When I make a purchase requisition for an item :

```
btn10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ITEM_SKU = Constants.ITENS[0].getCod();

            try {

                    token = getToken();

                    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), ITEM_SKU,RC_REQUEST,
                            FragmentPurchase.this, token);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

it is bought and appears successful payment message, but the service does not call the completion request, so I can not give status to the user.

This part is never called :

```
 @Override
public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {

    if (result.isFailure()) {
        ...
        return;
    }
    else if(info.getDeveloperPayload().equals(token)){
        ...
        mHelper.consumeAsync(info,
                FragmentPurchase.this);
    }
}
```

I've read in other answers and I have noted and implement all the tips, but it is still not calling the listener.

My class is also calling :

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent data)
{
    if (mHelper != null && !mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This is my onConsumeFinished :

```
@Override
public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
    Person person = func.getUser(view.getContext());
    Log.d(TAG, "Consumo do item.");
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        String menssage =  result.getMessage();
        int resultCode = result.getResponse();
        String sku = purchase.getSku();
        String tokenLocal = purchase.getDeveloperPayload();
        String[] params = {person.getId(),person.getAuth_token(),sku, String.valueOf(resultCode),menssage,tokenLocal};
        consumeItemWS(params);

    } else {
         Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "... " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             

    }
```

I do not know what's wrong, I have done according to the documentation, but it is not working.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Purchasing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html) page of the documentation? I can't confirm in  your code but you may need to set `queryInventoryAsync` with the listener you have for `onQueryInventoryFinished` to be called.

Comment: Got it, but I have onQueryInventoryFinished  and it is called in the initial, but the problem is that the onIabPurchaseFinished is not called, and the consumption and even if I call the onQueryInventoryFinished  would not work =(

Comment: Oh sorry I meant `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` and `onIabPurchaseFinished`, I can't edit my first comment anymore. You can check the [Purchase an item](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Purchase) section of the page if there's something that was missed.

Comment: I used this but the listener never called in launchPurchaseFlow =(